# How set column type as combobox or dropdown when using jquery DataTable plugin?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

```
var table = $('#DataTable_CentroCostos').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": "POST",
        "url": _pathGetDatosCetroCostos,
        "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "data": function (d, e) {
            return JSON.stringify({ _DtParameters: d, CC: model });
        }
    },
    "language": {
        "url": "../../Scripts/plugins/datatables/Spanish.json",
        "emptyTable": "No existen datos"
    },
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false
        },
        {
            'targets': 1,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
        },
        {
            'targets': 2,
            'searchable': true,
            'orderable': true
        },
        {
            'targets': 3,
            'searchable': true,
            'orderable': true
        },
        {
            'targets': 4,
            'searchable': true,
            'orderable': true
        },
        {
            'targets': 5,
            'searchable': true,
            'orderable': true
        }
    ],
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Id_Rel_Area" },
        { "data": "Id_Sociedad" },
        { "data": "Sociedad_Desc" },
        { "data": "CodCentroCosto" },
        { "data": "CodCentroCosto_Desc" },
        { "data": "Consolida_GS" }
    ],
    "scrollX": true,
    "destroy": true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make editable your table and specified type of column, you can use this code:

You can set the type of element `select` or `text` (check my example):

***Remember import the libraries:***

- jquery.min.js
- jquery.dataTables.min.js
- jquery.jeditable.js
- jquery.dataTables.editable.js
- jquery.validate.js

  ```
  var oTable = $("#table").DataTable();  

                  oTable.makeEditable({
                  sUpdateURL: "yourURL"),
                  aoColumns: [
                      {
                          cssclass: 'span12',
                          indicator: '<img src="../../recursos/img/loading.gif" height="16"/>',
                          tooltip: 'Doble click para cambiar el Cargo.',
                          loadtext: '<img src="../../recursos/img/loading.gif" height="16" />',
                          type: 'select',
                          style: 'margin: 0px; text-align: center; padding: 3px',
                          onblur: 'submit',
                          data: cargos,
                          fnOnCellUpdated: function (sStatus, sValue, settings) {

                          }
                      },
                      {
                          cssclass: 'fecha-inicio span12 required m-wrap',
                          indicator: '<img src="../../recursos/img/loading.gif" height="16"/>',
                          tooltip: 'Doble click para cambiar la fecha.',
                          loadtext: '<img src="../../recursos/img/loading.gif" height="16" />',
                          type: 'text',
                          style: 'margin: 0px; text-align: center; padding: 3px',
                          onblur: 'submit',
                          placeholder : 'dd/mm/YYYY',
                          fnOnCellUpdated: function (sStatus, sValue, settings) {

                          }
                      }
                  ]
              });
  ```